Sap oozing from stripped pine doors - over 100 years old!
Stripped pine doors reveal sticky sap in several places which does not reduce when wiped with methylated spirits. Is heating with heat gun the only solution to prepare for painting? Shellac (traditional knotting solution) doesn’t dry over it and aluminium primer dries but soon splits open showing that it is just a skin of paint floating on the surface.


sticky sap in several places which does not reduce when wiped with methylated spirits

It should have a reasonable solvent action as the constituents of pitch — various tree resins and balsams — are soluble in alcohols, and meths is primarily ethanol.
However the generally used solvents for removing these sticky residues are of a different type. Traditionally it was turpentine, and the standard replacement for turpentine is a replacement because it "works the same way" (i.e. has the same/similar solvent action). So, any form of white spirits; mineral spirits to the Americans.
Heating would certainly not hurt in addition to this, at minimum because solubility increases at higher temperatures. It's not clear if you have a heat gun but don't want to use it (doesn't matter why) or don't have one. But the resins soften at low temps, so basic hairdryers provide sufficient heating to aid the process.
Once you've removed the surface stuff knotting should dry fine, given that's precisely what it's for. However, test it separately. Knotting, as a pre-prepared shellac solution, automatically has a finite shelf life and if it's older (or especially OLD, like years old) it will either take far longer to dry than normal, many hours to days, or remain sticky 'permanently' according to many published sources.
If you test the knotting on any suitable surface like glass or glazed ceramic and discover it won't dry to a non-sticky film in well under an hour it should ideally be replaced.

Turpentine is sometimes distilled from pine sap. It may be possible to wipe down with turpentine.  If I remember correctly in the days before we had battery powered tools, when oil based paint was the norm, turpentine could be used to thin paint.  It may be possible to paint the door with an oil based paint after the turpentine wipe-down.  I'd leave maybe a day between the wipe-down and the paint application.

I found using a heat gun helped remove excess sap so that the stain blocking paint could dry out. Zinzer BIN did work well, even over previously painted wood where stains from sap had started to show. Thanks for info re knotting solution aging - I have thrown out 3 half used bottles as they weren’t drying out!
